# Updating data source after animating cell removal from UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a button in my custom cell that deletes the cell.
So i have a delegate that removes it.

code in view controller:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("swipeTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! swipeTableViewCell

    cell.initCell(self, indexPath: indexPath, text: data[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}
```

delegate method:

```
func removeCell(indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    data.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    table.beginUpdates()
    table.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    table.endUpdates()
}
```

code in cell:

```
func initCell(handler: handleCells, indexPath: NSIndexPath, text: String) {        
    self.handler = handler
    self.indexPath = indexPath
}
```

button pressed:

```
@IBAction func OnDelButtonClickListener(sender: UIButton) {
    self.handler.removeCell(indexPath)
}
```

This removes the cell with animation but the `reloadData` is not called and then the cells have the wrong `indexPath`.
So when I press a second cells delete the wrong cell gets removed.

If I call reloadData after  `table.endUpdates()` there is no animation.
if I call

```
let indexSet = NSIndexSet(index: indexPath.section)
self.table.reloadSections(indexSet, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
```

instead of

```
table.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
```

I don't get a removal animation.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Apple's programming guide for UITableViews, at the [row deleting section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW9).

I may be missing something in your code, but it looks like you don't actually delete the object in the datasource that corresponds to your deleted cell. Try removing the object from your datasource in the `removeCell` function before you delete the row.

```
func removeCell(indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    // here you delete the object form the datasource

    // after that, you do this
    table.beginUpdates()
    table.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    table.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: i edited my answer i forgot to copy that line of code to the question

Answer (score 0):

I think the key problem is in the Cell indexPath could not update when the table view delete the cell.

so we can try create a help array in the ViewController,help us update the really data to delate.

```
lazy var listHelper:Array<Int> = {
var array = [Int]()
for i in 0...self.data.count {
  array.append(i)
}
return array
}()
```

update the removeCell function to this :

```
func removeCell(indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
// if first delete  delete the date, and remove index in help list
if indexPath.row < listHelper.count - 1 && indexPath.row == listHelper[indexPath.row] {
  data.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
  tableView.beginUpdates()
  tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
  tableView.endUpdates()
    listHelper.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
}else {
  // if indexPath.row  != listHelper[indexPath.row],we find the really data we want to delete, used Array extension  .indexOf

  let locationData = listHelper.indexOf(indexPath.row)
  data.removeAtIndex(locationData!)


  // we create NSIndexPath and delete it.
  let theindexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: locationData!, inSection: 0)

  tableView.beginUpdates()
  tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([theindexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
  tableView.endUpdates()
  listHelper.removeAtIndex(locationData!)
}
}
```

the Extension of Array :

```
extension Array {
  func indexOf <U: Equatable> (item: U) -> Int? {
  if item is Element {
  return Swift.find(unsafeBitCast(self, [U].self), item)
  }
  return nil
 }
}
```

My English is poor. and U can see the code . I had try it, and it can work. I hope can solve you problem.